# Printing entire column from mysql using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to print the all of the contents in `column1 (Filename)` in `mysql` database, however, only the first row is being printed. I believe this is solved by using `while loop` in order to print the whole contents in that column. However I cannot get it to work.

**I have tried:**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

but it didn't work

This is the script that works but only prints the top row:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "123";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn)
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT Filename FROM Test";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Filename[] = $row['Filename'];

echo $row['Filename'];

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were not using while loop in proper way try this & use the data wherever you want

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
//$Filename[] = $row['Filename'];

//echo $row['Filename']."<br/>";

echo $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $Filename[] = $row['Filename'];
}
```